# USB drive data transfer control?

Tags: windows-8, security, usb-storage

I want to allow only authorized USB drives to transfer data from my computers.

How can this be achieved?

My computers have win 8/win 7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in action from only an end-user perspective from the product McAfee Device Control (http://www.mcafee.com/us/products/device-control.aspx). Basically the data admin has to receive the drive and then add it to the whitelist. Depending on how large and controlled this environment is and if it's a server+workstation type of environment you could use something like Microsoft Network Access Protection in a way that enforces having McAfee Device Control clients to be installed before being allowed to access the network.